# How to populate specific data from database into list item?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracleforms

I created ListItem1 with List Style (Poplist) for department no (10,20,30) and other ListItem2 with List Style (Tlist) for employees name. Record group for employees name

When i click on department no.10 then populate all employees name data into ListItem2. I want to populate data only employees names who falls under department no.10 or 20 or 30

**CODE:**

```
DECLARE

a VARCHAR2(100);
num NUMBER := 10;

BEGIN

a := populate_group ('R1');
    populate_list ('LIST1','R1');

END;
```

**"LIST1"** for populate employees name data
**"R1"** is a group record name

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just need to add `where department_no = :List1` to the R1 record group.

Answer (score 0):

In PL/SQL lists are called collections.

Try something like it:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE population_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY VARCHAR2(64);
  country_population population_type;
  continent_population population_type;
  howmany NUMBER;
  which VARCHAR2(64)

BEGIN
  country_population('Greenland') := 100000;
  country_population('Iceland') := 750000;
  howmany := country_population('Greenland');

  continent_population('Australia') := 30000000;
  continent_population('Antarctica') := 1000; -- Creates new entry
  continent_population('Antarctica') := 1001; -- Replaces previous 
value
  which := continent_population.FIRST; -- Returns 'Antarctica'
-- as that comes first alphabetically.
  which := continent_population.LAST; -- Returns 'Australia'
  howmany := continent_population(continent_population.LAST);
-- Returns the value corresponding to the last key, in this
-- case the population of Australia.
END;
```

Comment: You got it wrong, I think. This is a **Forms** question, not a (general) PL/SQL one. Forms' "list" is different from what you're saying.